# Get total amount of time (i.e. minutes or seconds) streamed for a track from Spotify API

Tags: spotify, spotipy, spotify-app

I am trying to build a project using my personal streaming history with Spotify. I plan on using the Spotify API as well as Spotipy (possibly).

Is there a way to find out how many minutes or seconds a particular track was streamed by me? I've already browsed questions which suggest Last.fm but this does not work retroactively.
Specifically, I want amount of time streamed for a track between (say) Mar 2019 to Mar 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request your streaming history by going into your settings on the spotify desktop site. It says it could take up to 30 days, I'm still waiting on mine.

Comment: Thank you for this!